# Exercise of class heritage java

Tags: java

I have this exercise to do classes that solve the problem. I'm starting with the world of object-oriented programming and it would help me a lot. I have this solution and I would like you to review it and I have some doubts as to whether it is ok, since it tells me that I can not modify the Contract class:
The contract class is the one I'm given as a reference

You want to create three new types of contracts:

> Premium. No Package is charged until you have sent 1000 but the final amount is increased € 699.
>
> Fragile. The first 100 fragile packages are not charged and after sending 100 fragile packages, only
>   charges one in two of this type. Non-fragile Packages are normally charged. The amount of
>   final amount.
>
> Plane. No package is charged. The final amount is an amount established when creating the contract but that
>   it can be modified later.

Prepare the class diagram of the problem solution and implement in Java the necessary classes to solve the new needs of the system, considering that we can not modify the existing classes, nor perform assumptions about how they have been implemented

```
public class Contract {
/ **
* Initialize a new contract for the Client c.
* /
public Contract (Client c) {

}

/ **
* Add Package p to the set of packages to be invoiced in a period of
* billing Package has methods that return boolean:
* isFragile () and isUrgent ().
* /
public void porte (Package p) {

}

/ **
* Returns the total invoice amount of a billing period.
* Contains fixed costs and charges for the packages sent.
* /
public double amount () {

}

/ **
* Reset the billing of a period.
* /
public void reset () {

 }
}
```

And I have

```
public class Package {

    public Package (){

    }

    public boolean isFragile(){
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isUrgent(){
        return true;
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Customer{

    private int CustomerNumber;

    public Customer(int CustomerNumber){
        this.CustomerNumber= CustomerNumber;

    }

    public int getCustomerNumber(){
        return CustomerNumber;
    }

}



public class Premium extends Contract {

    private int cont;

    public Premium(Customer c) {
        super(c);
        cont = 0;

    }

    @Override
    public void porte(Package p) {
        cont++;

    }

    @Override
    public double amount() {
        if (cont <= 1000){
            return 699;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override 
    public void reset(){
        cont = 0;
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Fragil extends Contract {

    private int cont;

    public Fragile(Customer c) {
        super(c);
        cont = 0;

    }

    @Override
    public void porte(Package p) {
        if (p.isFragile()) {
            cont++;
        }
        super.porte(p);
    }

    @Override
    public double amount(){
        return Math.floor((cont-100)*0.5);
    }

    @Override
    public void reset(){
        cont = 0;
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Plane extends Contract{

    public Plane(Customer c){
        super(c);

    }

    public void setPrize(double prize){
        super.prize = prize;

    }

    @Override 
    public double amount(){
        return super.getPrize();
    }

}
```

Comment: @AkinerAlkan At least before having put this misero comment, you could have deigned to see if there was someone who could help me (as they have). You can tell you have not read the first line. I'm starting with it and I wanted to check if the inheritance is well done, overwriting and others. I think with this I have said enough

Comment: Is there a particular reason as to why you aren't using abstract methods here if the Contract class is simply used to portray a concept vs. creating Objects from that class specifically?

Comment: @SimeonIkudabo That is the statement of the exercise. I have also seen that it could be easier to implement an interface, but in this way it forces me not to touch methods, not to suppose about the operation and overwrite (I say)

Comment: @Fernando ah I see. This assignment doesn't seem to follow the proper design pattern that would occur in real life. If the only point of the Contract class is for it to be inherited from, you'd either make it an interface or in some cases an abstract class. I'd ask your teacher "why" he wants you to do it this way.

Comment: @SimeonIkudabo Not being the most general solution due to the restrictions they put on me, would it be a valid solution?

Comment: @SimeonIkudabo I still have a question. For the premium class, the first 1000 have a cost of 0 and from 1001 onwards they start charging. How can I do it to get paid, with the information I have. I had thought about making a call super.porte(p) so that I could add that package to be charged, but I can not do super.amount() afterwards because I take things from the father and it would give me bad results, is not it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since this is exercise, I would recommend to continue and check it by yourself.
However, I'll give you some leads and things I've noticed in your approach.

First, you got the inheritance right.
Second, I've noticed you just count the number of packages (at least in Fragil contract) instead of calculating the billing. So you should determine how much each Package costs (you can hold this information as a private property of Package.

Plus, there is a problem writing this:

```
@Override
public double amount(){
    return Math.floor((cont-100)*0.5);
}
```

What if cont<100? lets say cont=40.
Then, the client will have to pay Math.floor(-60*0.5)=-30 instead of 0.
So you will head to rewrite this logic again.

Another thing,
this one doesn't make really sense... If the number of packages is 1000 or lower, there will be a fixed price of 699, but if there are more than 1000 - so the client shouldn't pay a penny? doesn't feel right..

```
@Override
public double amount() {
    if (cont <= 1000){
        return 699;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I guess what you should do in this kind of contract is setting that fixed price of 699, but starting from package number 1001 - you should add the cost of a package (same property I talked about before).

Hope i helped.

Comment: Yes, I know that I have to verify it on my own, but it is that the classes Contract is already specified and I can not modify them. The same goes for Package, which only has those two methods. Regarding the other thing that you tell me is true, they are incompatible states

Comment: Well.. so it might be a bad design of an exercise. I would, at least, defining the price somewhere (maybe inside the contracts)

Comment: The Plane class gives errors and is the one I doubt most, since the price is obtained when creating a contract, but the contract class I can not modify it. I have set a price set here, but I do not know if it is 100% correct. In principle yes, because it only changes in this class and not in the others that inherit

Comment: You use `super.getPrize()`, but Contract doesn't have such a method.

Comment: Therefore, that is the worst I have, because I have to miss information in the contract class ...

Comment: So just define it inside Plane - this particular type of contract has its own price. and you can get and set that property (and use it inside amount).

Comment: I still have a question. For the premium class, the first 1000 have a cost of 0 and from 1001 onwards they start charging. How can I do it to get paid, with the information I have. I had thought about making a call super.porte(p) so that I could add that package to be charged, but I can not do super.amount() afterwards because I take things from the father and it would give me bad results, is not it?

Comment: It seems you should get the amount from super.amount()

Comment: super.amount () I will take it well? Because the first 1000 are free and from there they start charging. If I call the super.amount () from Premium and, (assuming that it does a query to the method porte()), what method of porte() does it, to the parent class (Contract) or the daughter (Premium)?